# Why map Hammersley 2D set's (u,v) to sphere's (θ, φ) coordinates (and not to (φ, θ) )?

Tags: 2d, sampling, mapping, distribution, hemisphere

As explained in Holger Dammetz page [Hammersley Points on the Hemisphere](http://holger.dammertz.org/stuff/notes_HammersleyOnHemisphere.html), the 2D coordinates (u,v) are usually mapped to the spherical coordinates (θ, φ).
[image]
As a result, the coordinate "uniformly distributed" - u in the 2D case - is the polar angle θ. This looks counter-intuitive to me, I would have mapped regularly spaced u values to regularly spaced azimuth φ values. To avoid "empty areas" like in this example:
[image]
which is generated by the mapping of the following 2D set:
[image]
What is the reason not to map (u, v) to (φ, θ) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can of course, as you suggested, map (u, v) to (φ, θ). Unfortunately, it does not solve the problem for 5 points:

[image: Switched mapping]

I've changed Holger Dammertz' code a bit (switched u and v), and you see that the problem still persists. For a higher number of points, it really doesn't seem to make a (visual) difference.

The Hammersley point set is a way to **very quickly** determine points on a sphere that have good, but don't need to have a perfect distribution. In the problematic case of very few points, Hammersley might just not be the tool for the job. Pre-calculating and storing points sounds like a better option to me.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The "Uniform Mapping" here is incorrect.  It does not transform to a uniform distribution on the sphere.</strike>

Very very bad me.  I misread the equation AND I didn't even consult my own reference [1], if I had I would have seen my mistake.

Still the method from [2] is interesting and is described below.

## Additional note:

To map a uniform point set from the unit square to the sphere or half sphere requires an area-preserving map.  That will maintain the uniform property.  For pseudo-random that's sufficient (points are independent), however low-discrepancy point set will have its discrepancy measure effected by distortions in area introduced by the map.  I'm not aware of any references with respect to this point.

---

The method from [2] starts by mapping unit square to the unit disk.  One way we can do this is by using a rejection method.  Pseudo-code looks like this:

```
d = 0;

do {
  p = uniform2d(...);  // [0,1) x [0,1)   given to be uniform
  p = 2p;              // [0,2) x [0,2)   scaling (area-preserving)
  p = p-1;             // (-1,1) x (-1,1) translating (area-preserving)
  d = dot(p,p);        // is p in disk?
} while(d >= 1);       //   if not rinse-and-repeat
```

the area of the transformed square is $4$ and the unit disk is $\pi$, so the acceptance rate is $\frac{\pi }{4}$ (~.785) so on average requires $\frac{4}{\pi}$ (~1.273) iterations.

Also non-rejection based methods exist, for example [3] which requires one square root and one trig operation. Note that the rejection method does not distort areas so the discrepancy measure remains the same.

---

Once we have $ p = \left(u_0, u_1 \right) $ uniformly distributed in the unit disk, we have:

$$ u_0, u_1 \in \left(-1,1\right) $$
$$ d = p\cdot p = u_0^2+u_1^2,\; d < 1 $$

then the transform to the sphere is:

$$ s=2\sqrt{1-d} $$
$$ p = \left\{s\thinspace u_0,\thinspace s\thinspace u_1, 1-2d\right\} $$

or if you wanted a half-sphere, say positive Z, (just to state the obvious):

$$p = \left\{s\thinspace u_0,\thinspace s\thinspace u_1, d\right\} $$

There is a Stackexchange: Mathematics thread that discusses this method ([4],[5]).

---

Also if you want to procedurally generate a LDS the additive recurrence formulation of the Weyl sequence is very cheap.

---

References:

1. [Wolfram MathWorld: Sphere Point Picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html)
2. "Choosing a Point from the Surface of a Sphere.", George Marsaglia, 1972. ([PDF](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177692644;))
3. [Wolfram MathWorld: Disk Point Picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html)
4. [SE Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838326/3-random-numbers-to-describe-point-on-a-sphere/838336#838336)
5. [SE Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838326/3-random-numbers-to-describe-point-on-a-sphere/838882#838882)

Comment: Doh:  actually I'm wrong about the method not being uniform...working on a rewrite.

Comment: OK, I put up a first revision.

Comment: Added the area-distortion note